# Why not aggregating rows first in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I am confused about why I can't get average value for each row by mean() in data.table.

```
> aaa <- data.table(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
> aaa[, `:=` (avg = mean(V1 + V2 +V3), onethird = (V1 + V2 +V3)/3)]
> aaa
   V1 V2 V3 avg onethird
1:  1  4  7  15        4
2:  2  5  8  15        5
3:  3  6  9  15        6
```

It seems what data.table did is **mean(V1) + mean(V2) + mean(V3)** rather than **mean(V1 + V2 +V3)**.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Actually I want to generate some more columns by calculating the average value of other columns, like getting avg12 from V1 and V2, getting avg345 from V3, V4 and V5.

```
> aaa <- data.table(matrix(1:10, nrow = 2))
> aaa[, `:=` (avg12 = (V1 + V2)/2, avg345 = (V3 + V4 + V5)/3)]
> aaa
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 avg12 avg345
1:  1  3  5  7  9     2      7
2:  2  4  6  8 10     3      8
```

Is it possible to use some simple mean function on (V1 + V2) or (V1, V2)?

Comment: `aaa[, V1 + V2 + V3]` gives `c(12,15,18)` - the mean of which is `15`

Comment: Thanks, @thelatemail. Now I realize that mean() only works on single column.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - 'why does mean() not aggregate across rows in data.table?' maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans` to get the `mean` of each row.  It can also be applied directly to the dataset (`.SD` - Subset of Data.table, when we don't specify the `.SDcols`, it takes all the columns in the dataset)

```
aaa[, `:=` (avg = rowMeans(.SD), onethird = (V1 + V2 + V3)/3)]
```

---

Or another option is get the sum by row with `Reduce` and then divide by the number of columns (`length(.SD)`)

```
aaa[, `:=` (avg = Reduce(`+`, .SD)/length(.SD), onethird = (V1 + V2 +V3)/3)]
```

Comment: aaa <- data.table(matrix(1:10, nrow = 2));
aaa[, mean12 := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = c("V1", "V2")];
aaa[, mean345 := rowMeans(.SD), .SDcols = c("V3", "V4", "V5")];

Comment: @dhhan  What is your question?

Comment: This could be a solution. It is simple though not in just one statement.

Comment: @dhhan Fyi, it would be even simpler if your data set was shaped correctly for analysis in R (in "long format"). Btw, you should probably post a new question rather than editing in a big extension (unless you ask akrun / other answerers first to see if they're fine with the extension).